# Accessing hour,minute and second using Calendar class

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to set an alarm on a particular day and time.So setting hour and minute using `Calendar`.But when i try to access the hour which is set in `Calendar` using `cal.set`,i get a different value than that was set by me manually.

**Code**

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,7);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm worked. "+cal.HOUR+cal.MINUTE,cal.SECOND Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Result i want**

Alarm worked. 7:30:0

**What i get now**

Alarm worked. 10:12:13

**P.S**

1.I found many posts which deal with `Calendar` issues but couldn't find my solution.

2.The result what i am getting i.e `10:12:13` is not my current time(current date,current minute,current second) either.So i don't know why and from where these data are coming.

3.I tried using `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `HOUR` but nothing useful.

**Solution**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm worked. "+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)+" "+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This worked because `Calendar.HOUR`,`Calendar.MINUTE` are constants.See the answer of @PopoFibo to get the clear picture.

Comment: Please see the Original post.It shows `Alarm worked. 10:12:13

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `Toast`, you are printing the constants of the `Calendar` class:

```
Calendar.HOUR = 10
Calendar.MINUTE = 12
Calendar.SECOND = 13
```

Instead, get the value at their respective indexes - like for `HOUR` it would be `cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)`

```
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

**Would give (correct output):**

```
7:30:0
```

And, `System.out.println(Calendar.HOUR + ":" + Calendar.MINUTE + ":" + Calendar.SECOND);`

**Would give (incorrect output):**

```
10:12:13
```

Comment: Perfect.Works like a charm.`Calendar.HOUR` is a constant.Got it.Thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Hey @PopoFibo could you please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482969/formatting-miliseconds-to-hhmmss-format) too?Another silly problem there i guess.

Comment: please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508611/alarm-cancel-button-not-working-correctly) if you could please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> **Date s = cal.getTime();
> SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
> String t = sdf.format(s);
>             
>   Toast.makeText(this, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();**
>  for more ref. see http://www.asbhtechsolutions.com/android-tutorial/1-android-get-current-time-and-date

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.Though it seems right but it didn't work in my case.Please see my edit for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

and then toast it

Comment: Tried this but same issue.I don't know from where these 10 12 13 are coming!

Answer (score 0):

add these lines before setting time..

```
                Cal.set(Calendar.MONTH , month);
                Cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                Cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.But this didn't work.However i fixed it with the help of above answer.Please check my edit.