# Confusion regarding number of alarms needed to be set

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

I have the following data in `SqlLite` as well as `Postgresql` database and am successfully showing it in a `tablularlayout` on my android widget.It's basically a timetable for college students.

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/1w7Tyicfce/random3.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/1w7Tyicfce/random3.png)

I did set `OnClickListener` for all the `textviews` individually,which means each and every subject name which you're seeing is clickable in my app.

Upon clicking on a subject name i.e a `textview`,a page shows up as following.

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/Ii8DtkvJba/setalarm.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/Ii8DtkvJba/setalarm.png)

Till now I have written code for setting up a single alarm only but not multiple.Hence selecting one `checkbox` only.However i am gonna set multiple alarms such that if one selects all the 4 `checkboxes` 4 alarms for a single subject must be triggering accordingly.

**Question**

1.While setting alarms for each subject individually,should i set 4 `pendingintents` for 4 `checkbox` selected time and only trigger those alarms which are selected in `checkboxes`?And should i use the same `requestcode` for the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` or should i use 4 different `requestcodes`?Right now i have only 1 `pendingintent`.When `save and set alarm` button is clicked one alarm is being set according to the selected `checkbox` time.But i think this is not the right way for achieving the result.

2.I am assuming that i have to create 4 `pendingintents` for "one subject at one particular slot,for eg. for DBMS its monday 1:40-3:20PM,so 4 `pendingintents` for DBMS".Now in total do i need to create `No. of subjects * 4` number of `pendingintents` each having different`requestcodes`?

**Note**

As it may be a little confusing please comment below if something is not clear in my question.

Comment: Doesn't look like this actually has anything to do with PostgreSQL, right? This is about Android user interface and client code?

Comment: Well yes you're right but as the image on top of the post was taken from my postgresql database i put `postgresql` tag.Could you please help me with the main issue?

Comment: No, I can't, I don't do Android. Just making sure there wasn't a PostgreSQL issue I could help with here.

Comment: Oh okay.Thanks for your concern anyways.

Comment: @Sash_kp if you found the answer, add an answer to your question and accept it as answer. Don't edit your post with "[solved]".

Comment: Hey @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Thanks for your suggestion.Yeah surely i'll do that from now onward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and short answer is `The number of alarms for different time slots needed,the same number of pendingintents are needed to be created.`