# Alarm "cancel" button not working correctly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I have 2 buttons `save and set alarm` and `cancel alarm` which are meant to do exactly what they suggest.

**Inside onCreate declared variables**

```
final Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

**Code inside Cancel Button onClickListener**

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

if (alarmUp)
            {

                  new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                  .setTitle("Alert")
                  .setMessage("This alarm will be deleted.")
                  .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                        alarmManager.cancel(sender1);
                                        sender1.cancel();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                    }


                                })
                                .create().show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Alert")
                                    .setMessage("Alarm for this is not set yet.")
                                 .setPositiveButton("Ok",null)
                                .create().show();
                                }
```

**Code for save button**

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, 
                             alarmintent, 
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);


                        if (alarmUp)
                        {
                            //Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Alert")
                            .setMessage("Already an alarm is set for this particular time and day.")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",null    
                            )

                            .create().show();
                        }
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis()+5000,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, sender1);
```

When i click `save` for the first time it shows

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/puMWZEvRba/alert1.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/puMWZEvRba/alert1.png)

However as i have `cancel` too i can click that to cancel the alarm.So i click `cancel` button and it shows

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/1UOTyVK0ce/alert2.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/1UOTyVK0ce/alert2.png)

which seems right.But when i again click `save` button it shows

[a http://www.4shared.com/download/puMWZEvRba/alert1.png](http://www.4shared.com/download/puMWZEvRba/alert1.png)

which means the `cancel` button is not doing what it should do although it executes the `toast` for `this alarm will be deleted.`.Which again means there must be some problem with `alarmManager.cancel(sender1)`.

**Question**

What to modify in the code to get the `cancel` button work correctly?

**P.S**

I referred many posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330522/how-to-cancel-this-repeating-alarm) but can't get what's the exact problem in my case.

**Updated Code**

**For cancel button**

```
final Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);

if (alarmUp)
            {

                  new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                  .setTitle("Alert")
                  .setMessage("This alarm will be deleted.")
                  .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                                        alarmManager.cancel(sender1);
                                        sender1.cancel();
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                    }


                                })
                                .create().show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                                    .setTitle("Alert")
                                    .setMessage("Alarm for this is not set yet.")
                                 .setPositiveButton("Ok",null)
                                .create().show();
                                }
```

**For Save Button**

```
 final Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, 
                             alarmintent, 
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);


                        if (alarmUp)
                        {
                            //Log.d("myTag", "Alarm is already active");
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("Alert")
                            .setMessage("Already an alarm is set for this particular time and day.")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",null    
                            )

                            .create().show();
                        }
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,c.getTimeInMillis()+5000,24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, sender1);
```

This results in same as previous.`Cancel` button doesn't seem to work.

**Solution**

Thanks to **@David Wasser** i got it working now.Please see his answer.I also had to change

`boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, 
                                        alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null)`

to

`boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, 
                                        alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null)` in both the blocks.

But as [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) says `FLAG_NO_CREATE Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then simply return null instead of creating it.`I don't know about this issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things are wrong here:

1 Don't use `Intent.FILL_IN_DATA` in the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`. This is an `Intent` flag and not a `PendingIntent` flag. It doesn't belong here.

2 When you use the `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` this will return `null` if the `PendingIntent` doesn't already exist. In your code to set `alarmUp` you've got the comparison against `null` backwards. **NOTE: See my comments at the end of this answer about the fact that the documentation for this is wrong**

3 In your `onCreate()` you are doing this:

```
PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2,
      alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT |  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

This line will create the `PendingIntent` even if you don't set an alarm with it. Later, when you check if the `PendingIntent` exists with this code:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, 
      alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);
```

`alarmUp` will always be `false`, because you have already created the `PendingIntent` in `onCreate()`.

NOTE: The `PendingIntent` is created when you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, not when you set the alarm.

---

**EDIT: Add more code examples**

As I said earlier, you can't create the `PendingIntent` if you want to use it to determine whether the alarm is set or not. You must first check if the `PendingIntent` exists and then you can create it to set/cancel it. To fix, do this:

In **cancel button**:

```
final Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Determine if the alarm has already been set
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
if (alarmUp) {
    final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ...
```

In **save button**:

```
final Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Determine if the alarm has already been set
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
if (alarmUp) {
    final PendingIntent sender1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ...
```

---

**EDITED again to fix documentation discrepancy with `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`**:

Note: It seems the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) about `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE`  **is wrong!** It says:

> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
>   then simply return null instead of creating it.

but this is backwards. This method will return the `PendingIntent` if it already exists. **It will return `null` if it doesn't already exist**.

I've edited my answer to reflect the correct operation of this flag.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand why you are getting NullPointerException. I also don't understand why you need to use same `PendingIntent` in both blocks. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand the problem. You can create a `PendingIntent` outside of `onCreate()`. However, you can't create anything that requires a `Context` until the component has been initialized (ie: **after `onCreate()` has been called**). Also, you don't need to use the same `PendingIntent` object. If you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` with the same set of parameters you will get a reference to the same `PendingIntent`. If you say you've tried it and it didn't work, please add the revised code to your original question so we can look at it.

Comment: I added code examples in my answer. I hope this is now clear. You can create the `PendingIntent` outside of `onCreate()`. You can put it in another method. You just can't do it **before** `onCreate()` is called (ie: in the constructor or in a static initalizer). But you don't need to do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions.You're awesome.It was the issue there.But i had to change `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 2,alarmintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null` in both the blocks!But [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_NO_CREATE) says it should return `null` if `pendingintent` already exists!Is it a bug?

Comment: Good point. I didn't see that. I'll need to check that myself.

Comment: I did accept your answer and also edited my post.Please check my edit.And Please edit your answer what you think about the `!null` issue after checking.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The documentation is wrong! It never ceases to amaze me that the docs contain incorrect information for so long. I'll edit my answer as well.

Comment: @A.Adam please post a new question with your code. This isn't the right place to ask a new question.