# AlarmManager - deleting/checking alarms not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to do following:

1) cancel an alarm

2) check if an alarm exists...

To test this, I do following:

```
 public static void startUpdater(Context context)
{
    // START TEST CODE
    cancelAllAlarms(context);
    alarmExists(context);
    // END TEST CODE

    if (true)// !alarmExists(context))
    {
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = getAlarmPendingIntent(context);

        Calendar calNextAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        calNextAlarm.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        calNextAlarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calNextAlarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calNextAlarm.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        L.d(Updater.class, "Alarm wird registriert..." + calNextAlarm.getTime().toLocaleString());

        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                calNextAlarm.getTimeInMillis(),
                86400000, // repeat once a day
                pi);
    }
}

private static void cancelAllAlarms(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = getAlarmPendingIntent(context);
    try
    {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
        L.d(Updater.class, "AlarmManager canceled!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        L.d(Updater.class, "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
    }
}

private static Intent getAlarmIntent(Context context)
{
    return new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
}

private static PendingIntent getAlarmPendingIntent(Context context)
{
    return getAlarmPendingIntent(context, false);
}

private static PendingIntent getAlarmPendingIntent(Context context, boolean flagNoCreate)
{
    Intent i = getAlarmIntent(context);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, flagNoCreate ? PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE : 0);
    return pi;
}

private static boolean alarmExists(Context context)
{
    boolean exists = getAlarmPendingIntent(context, true) != null;
    L.d(Updater.class, "AlarmManager exists: " + exists);
    return exists;
}
```

But after cancelling the alarm, my check functions still returns true... Can someone point out my error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Instead of this

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
            flagNoCreate ? PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE : 0);
```

Comment: I tried setting this flag for the `PendingIntent` in my cancel function but still afterwards my check functions returns true...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508611/alarm-cancel-button-not-working-correctlysolved

Comment: that helped... For checking and canceling, I need to create the `PendingIntent` with the flag `FLAG_NO_CREATE`. In my case, I'm always creating an `PendingIntent` in  my cancel function and therefore, afterwards my check function returns true

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to say I was struggling with this problem recently and discovered that I needed to cancel the PendingIntent as well as the Alarm:

```
pi.cancel();
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
```

I'm not sure if that's negated by the advice felix gave but whenever I was creating a PendingIntent (with the aim of cancelling an alarm) I always did it the exact same way I did when creating the alarm with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. For example:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Hope that helps.