# why java program is outputting the following

Tags: java, time, calendar

Below is the code for implementing time server

**Server class**

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
   try{
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(990);
             Socket s=ss.accept();
            while(true)
            {
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                out.println("Hello This is server & My Time is :");
                out.println("Time :::  Hour="+c.HOUR +" Min="+c.MINUTE +" sec="+c.SECOND);
            out.flush();
              s.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Client class**

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
   try{
            ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(990);
             Socket s=ss.accept();
            while(true)
            {
                Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
                out.println("Hello This is server & My Time is :");
                out.println("Time :::  Hour="+c.HOUR +" Min="+c.MINUTE +" sec="+c.SECOND);
            out.flush();
              s.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

the program is working but the output is always

```
time:: hour=10 min=12 sec=13
```

why it is outputting the above values

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478193/accessing-hour-minute-and-second-using-calendar-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're printing the values of the static integer fields called [`HOUR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR), [`MINUTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE), [`SECOND`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SECOND) present in the `Calendar` class. You need to use the [`Calendar#get(field)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) method to get the `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND` values from the Calendar.

```
out.println("Time :::  Hour="+c.get(Calendar.HOUR) +" Min="+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" sec="+c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Note that since HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND are `static` fields, you need to access them using the class name(`Calendar.SECOND`) and not using the instance(`c.SECOND`).

Comment: getting the current time is not an issue, i did that with c.gettime() and simpledateformat, but i only want to know even though i have not assigned values to them why are they printing 10,12 and 13 everytime?

Comment: They are assigned. Calendar.HOUR is an Integer with the value 10.

Comment: That's because `HOUR` is a static integer field already present in the Calendar class. And the value for that is `10` and the same goes for `MINUTE` and `SECOND`. You shouldn't mistake the Calendar fields with the actual hour, minute and second data.